# headless blind remote unattended Bluetooth pairing

Tags: bluetooth

I need a Pi to pair promiscuously with anything with a Bluetooth antenna, because we need to use it headless, in the field, with no desktop, to pair to a Brand X tablet.

Here's the existing literature on headless pairing. Even after I upgraded it to use modern commands, it is fragile and inconsistent:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=170353

Now other literature recommends this to turn on discovery:

`sudo bt-adapter --set Discoverable 1`

The `bluez-tools` package provides `bt-adapter`? `man bt-adapter` does not discuss automatic pairing. Should I run `bt-agent` as a daemon and allow it to pair with anyone with the correct passkey?

---

Another problem: When I activated the network-over-Bluetooth system, PAN, it destroyed autopairing from both the old and new systems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
```

per [Automatically accept bluetooth pairings](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/automatically-accept-bluetooth-pairings)

Comment: The [question you referenced](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/automatically-accept-bluetooth-pairings) has 6 answers (as of today). The [answer that apparently resolved your issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96100/83790) has no votes (up or down). I'm confused... if this resolved your issue, why no upvote, but did it actually solve your issue?

Comment: apologies for overreacting. We had a Pi Zero W in the field simply lose its adapter chip entirely, so when it was running headless we couldn't tell if the discovery failed or what. The next time I build a new controller I will confirm things work, then upvote them.