# How to make sure BlueZ NoInputNoOutput agent does not ask for user authorization?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-os-buster, bluez

I am trying to pair my custom made BLE device with a Raspberry Pi 4, using the [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) library, programmatically. I do not want to press "accept" or type "yes" whenever I try to pair. I want it to accept pairing automatically. However, whenever I try to pair using the *bluepy* *pair()*, method, a prompt shows up asking to accept or reject pairing, every time.

This question is similar to [Automatically accept bluetooth pairings](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/automatically-accept-bluetooth-pairings), however, none of the solutions seem to work.

I've run the following code in a terminal:

```
sudo bluetoothctl
pairable on
agent NoInputNoOutput
default-agent
```

which have been suggested other places. When I do this inside a terminal, I instead get a text prompt, forcing me to type "yes" in order to accept the pairing. So I still get the prompt, just in a different place. Is there a way to make *bluetoothctl* automatically accept new pairings? Maybe there is some documentation on how to set up the bluetoothctl agent in such a way that it does not prompt the user for every new device? I've tried to use *subprocess* in Python to script the bluetoothctl input, however, it always fail to when it comes to typing "yes" on the annoying prompt.

I have also tried:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan 
sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
```

However, this results in a "Authentication Failed" error using the Bluepy library. Now there is no prompt, the pairing is simply rejected.

In the source code I basically do:

```
from bluepy.btle import Peripheral
peripheral = Peripheral('aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff')
peripheral.pair()
```

Comment: Is this similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403748/7721752  ?

Comment: Thanks @ukBaz. It helped. I am now using the *dbus* interface, with a custom python *agent* which does not require user authorization. I am running the dbus main loop in a separate thread than *bluepy*, but bluepy seem to work together with that custom agent.

Comment: @robino16 what Agent method is called when using NoInputNoOutput? I'm trying the same but the latest seems to be broken: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324225