# Auto accept bluetooth pairings

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I want to automatically accept Bluetooth pairings with any device that wants to connect, I tried all answers (without python ones) from this question:
[Automatically accept bluetooth pairings](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/automatically-accept-bluetooth-pairings)
But they don't work for me, if I try to connect to Raspberry Pi, **it connects for 10 seconds and then disconnects and prints error aborted by local**. I have Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W. I am running latest Raspberry Pi OS.

On my computer when I run bluetoothctl - B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E is Raspberry Pi

```
[bluetooth]# connect B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E
Attempting to connect to B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E Connected: yes
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-unknown
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E Connected: no
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E Connected: yes
[CHG] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E Connected: no
[DEL] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E raspberrypi
[NEW] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E raspberrypi
[DEL] Device B8:27:EB:9C:DB:9E raspberrypi
```

Raspberry pi log:

```
[NEW] Device 04:42:1A:5A:42:1B mnxd 
[CHG] Device 04:42:1A:5A:42:1B Connected: no


> HCI Event: Simple Pairing Complete (0x36) plen 7                                                                                                                                           #1 [hci0] 29.091890
        Status: Authentication Failure (0x05)
        Address: 04:42:1A:5A:42:1B (OUI 04-42-1A)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8                                                                                                                                    {0x0001} [hci0] 29.091998
        BR/EDR Address: 04:42:1A:5A:42:1B (OUI 04-42-1A)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                                                                               #2 [hci0] 29.092843
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 12
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
```

Comment: What is it that is trying to connect to the RPi? Often that error message is because the connecting device is requesting a service on the RPi that doesn't exist so it disconnects it. Do you have `bluetoothctl` running on the RPi? What is reported in that? Also have `sudo btmon` running. The output is very verbose but it might give more information to debug this.

Comment: `it connects for 10 seconds and then disconnects and prints error aborted by local` ... what connects to what? ... what prints the error?

Comment: @jsotola I connect my computer running Arch Linux to Raspberry Pi. Error prints blueman-manager on my computer

Comment: @ukBaz Yes I have bluetoothctl running on my Raspberry Pi, btmon doesn't print anything when I try to connect to Raspberry Pi. This is error that after some time bleman-manager prints: Connection Failed: le-connection-abort-by-local. I think this error is because I cannot click allow to pair on my raspberry pi.

Comment: Well done on updating your question with the `bluetootchctl` log. That is the `bluetoothctl` log from the Arch Linux computer. What is the `bluetoothctl` log from the RPi? Try setting up a GATT Server on the RPi and then see if the Arch Linux machine can connect and stay connected.

Comment: Instead of a comment, please edit your question with the log. Not only will it be formatted to be more readable, but it will be indexed better with search engines.

Comment: I followed https://scribles.net/creating-ble-gatt-server-uart-service-on-raspberry-pi/ tutorial on how to set up a GATT server, and it finally started working. Thank you