# How can I make Raspberry Pi's Bluetooth discoverable to iPhone or iOS?

Tags: bluetooth, android, raspberry-pi-desktop, ios

I've got a Raspberry Pi 4B,
when I use an Android phone to connect to the Pi with Bluetooth, it works normally, both pairing and connection.
But when I use an iPhone to do the same thing, the phone can not see Pi's Bluetooth, it means, the Pi's Bluetooth is not discoverable to iPhone.
(However, the iPhone's Bluetooth is dicoverable to raspberry, but this is not what I need.)

Could anyone tell me, is there anything special of iPhone's Bluetooth?
What should I do if I want to make Pi's Bluetooth be discoverable to iPhone or iOS?
I want to connect to Pi's Bluetooth from iPhone.

I asked this question in stackoverflow,too. Here is the link.

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788077/how-can-i-make-raspberry-pis-bluetooth-discoverable-to-iphone [1]

Maybe I should do some iOS programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect an iPhone to a Pi 3B with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/connect-an-iphone-to-a-pi-3b-with-bluetooth-low-energy). In short, there is no free lunch to be had here.

Comment: to Dmitry Grigoryev: If the only way to solve this is to do iOS development, I think this answered my question.